# Is Write/Read pin in LCD is need to changed every time? Or is it ok if we fixed it to write only?

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, power-electronics, microprocessor, character-lcd

We are using 16X2 LCD. In that we are only going to write to LCD we are not going to read anything from it. Is it ok if we put it as write pin ? or every time after writing do we need to change it as read pin? Is there any problem if we only use it for writing. (My friend was saying if we use it as only write pin over the period junk character issue will come .) Is it true??

Comment: You will get better answers if you link to the datasheet. Also describe what is driving your lcd, and where any risk of spurious signals may come from.

Comment: You can safely ground it... Never observed any junk characters

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean an HD44780-compatible LCD.

The state of the R/W pin does not need to change between writes. You can safely wire it to ground if you will never need to read from the display.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Ya, I have done the same. I have wired it into ground. My friend is saying if you don't toggle it u will see junk character issues over the period . Is it true? . Have you found any such cases?